# flexiable android static variable

Tags: android

I use `HttpClient` in my android application.

My code is as follows:

```
private static String url = "http://127.0.0.1/q?=xxx";
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();    
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url); 
HttpResponse response;
response = client.execute(request);
```

My question is that I have several activities that use this piece of code.

Is there anyway to extract the static variable "url" so that I can change it in one location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to create a `class` which contains all of your static variables, something like this:

```
public class Constants {
    public static final String URL = "http://127.0.0.1/q?=xxx";
}
```

That way you can use `Constants.URL` everywhere in your application, but you have to change it only once.